# Marker display in my JavaScript V3 Google Map, but not in Google Live Map

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I am building a google map project, I am using google JavaScript v3 api, everything is fine and markers display in my custom map, but when I want to see direction and click any marker and it takes well to google live map, **but there I do not see my marker**, my question is all my custom added markers will display at google live map or it is just separate map?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will follow the guidelines in future.

Comment: You can edit the question and improve it, no need to wait for the future ;)